# Initialize 2 dimensional array inside nested loop

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am working on an issue where i need to Declare a two - dimensional array named multiplicationTable
that contains 4 elements by 4 elements.Initialize it in
a nested loop to contain elements that equal to the value
that is the product of the two index values for
each element. In a second nested loop, display the values
in the console output, with column elements separated with
commas, and row elements separated with carriage returns. This is what i have so far, for some reason can't wrap my brain around the solution! Any help would be appreciated!.

```
        double[,] multiplicationTable = new double[4, 4];// { {1,2,3,4 }, {5,6,7,8 }, {9,10,11,12 }, {13,14,15,16 } };

        for (int i = 0; i < multiplicationTable.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < multiplicationTable.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                double d = multiplicationTable[i, j];
                if (j < multiplicationTable.GetLength(1) - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(d + ",");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(d);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: So what's the problem here? Are you having trouble populating the table? Printing the table? Both? Does you code work? If not, what does it do that isn't what you expected?

Comment: The problem is I need the output to look like this:

Comment: 0,0,0,0
0,1,2,3
0,2,4,6
0,3,6,9
basically the product of the two index values for each element

Comment: the original code was designed to iterate through a two dimensional array putting each row on a separate line separated by commas, now i need to modify it using a blank 4x4 array to the specs listed

Answer (score 0):

```
        double[,] multiplicationTable = new double[4, 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < multiplicationTable.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < multiplicationTable.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                multiplicationTable[i, j] = i * j;
                double d = multiplicationTable[i, j];
                if (j < multiplicationTable.GetLength(1) - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(d + ",");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(d);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: It was so easy it eluded me ... working too late put my brain in a fog!

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to solve this with [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method? It is easy to use and will save you a lot of if-else statements. Here it is how it will look like with this method:

```
double[,] multiplicationTable = new double[4, 4] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15, 16 } };

for (int i = 0; i < multiplicationTable.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    var temp = new string[4];
    for (int j = 0; j < multiplicationTable.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        temp[j] = multiplicationTable[i, j].ToString();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", temp));
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: It was an exercise where I had to ".Initialize it in a nested loop to contain elements that equal to the value that is the product of the two index values for each element" so the array would not be populated to begin with.  But your code does work, thank you

Comment: I do like the Join method however, it's slick. Modified like this it works great!

Comment: I am glad to help you. I do like Join too, as it saves a lot of Ifs

Answer (score 0):

```
double[,] multiplicationTable = new double[4, 4];

for (int i = 0; i < multiplicationTable.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    var temp = new string[multiplicationTable.GetLength(0)];
    for (int j = 0; j < multiplicationTable.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        multiplicationTable[i, j] = i * j;
        temp[j] = multiplicationTable[i, j].ToString();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", temp));
}
```